# How to use OAuth2.0 for Google Calender API in Android?

Tags: android, api, authorization, oauth-2.0

My android app is designed to fetch calendars and events from Google. I downloaded Google API v3 and followed the example from official tutorial. In the tutorial, it uses Account Manager to do authorisation for android, which means user can directly pickup an account already set on android device to get authorisation done.

```
startActivityForResult(CalendarHelper.getInstance().credential.newChooseAccountIntent(), REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER);
```

The code runs good, but I don't want authorisation this way. I prefer the way that start a webview and open an url which lead user to a login page, after he login and accept the permissions, the taken will be returned to access calendar data, just like the Google API in iOS.

I understand the workflow of OAuth 2.0, but I can't find any sample code on android to do authorisation the way I described above.

Can any one help?

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding `approval_prompt=force` in your HTTP request that you make while looking for access tokens. This parameter ensures that the user has to log in/provide credentials every time the app is run.

Quoting from Google's [documentation.](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer)

> "If the value is force, then the user sees a consent page even if they
>   have previously given consent to your application for a given set of
>   scopes."